# Python - Create directory and move specific file

Tags: python, subprocess, shutil

Learning and understanding Python better I want to write a script based on youtube-dl that downloads a playlist and moves all those flv videos in a specific directory.

This is my code so far:

```
import shutil
import os
import sys
import subprocess
# Settings
root_folder = 'C:/Users/Robert/Videos/YouTube/Playlists/$s'

def download():
    files = open('Playlists.txt').readlines()

    for playlist in files:
        p = playlist.split(';')

    # Create the directory for the playlist if it does not exist yet
    if not os.path.exists (root_folder % p[0]):
        os.makedirs(root_folder % p[0])

    # Download every single video from the given playlist
    download_videos = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'youtube-dl.py', ['-cit'], [p[1]]])        
    download_videos.wait()

    # Move the video into the playlist folder once it is downloaded
    shutil.move('*.flv', root_folder % p[0])


download()
```

The structure of my Playlists.txt looks as follows:

```
Playlist name with spaces;http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBECF255AE8287C0F&feature=view_all
```

I run into two problems. First of all the string formatting does not work.

I get the error:

```
Playlist name with spaces
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\downloader.py", line 27, in <module>
    download()
  File ".\downloader.py", line 16, in download
    if not os.path.exists (root_folder % p[0]):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Can anybody explain me the reason? When I print p[0] everything looks fine.

Second, I do not have any clue how to set the correct shutil.move command to only move the flv video that was just downloaded. How can I filter that?

Thank you!

Comment: I hope your code is indented properly on your system, otherwise your `p = playlist.split(';')` line won't do what you want.

Comment: Of course it is. I edited my code above accordingly. Thanks for the notice!

Comment: Edit to the questions are only to provide-more information or improvements (with improvements I mean formatting improvements, fixing of type, etc..). Any other changes will change the question, hence the answers that you already have will have no sense anymore. Please rollback to a previous [edit] accept the answer that helped you the most. You're welcome to open a new question stating your new problem :)

Comment: Hello Rik, 

I was not aware of that. Sorry. I did the rollback accordingly. 

I simply wanted to point out that the first problem is solved and the second one still persists.

Should I open a new question for that one or just leave it here?

Comment: @orschiro: Don't worry :) I'd say that with a new question you'll have better chanches to get new ansers that will solve your problem.

Comment: @orschiro: Off topic general advice on how SO works (beacuse better questions will lead to better answers): If you want to reply to some comment you might need to use `@` (check out [how `@replies` works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/177799)). The more focused is the piece of code on the error that you get, easier it will be for others to see why it fails. There are a couple of good guides [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18614/177799) and [here](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). These are just advices for your next question (if you want to follow them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm not on windows**

The main point is that you should use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for joining paths.

But there seems to be a couple of problems with this string:

```
root_folder = 'C:/Users/Robert/Videos/YouTube/Playlists/$s'
```

I think that:

- <del>you need to use double escaped backslahses.</del>
- You meant `%s` instead of `$s`.
- There's no need anyway for `%s`,  [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is the cross platform way for joining paths.
- [optional] imho backsleshes are more readable.

So I'd say that you need to change that line to:

```
root_folder = 'C:/Users/Robert/Videos/YouTube/Playlists'
```

or

```
root_folder = 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Videos\\YouTube\\Playlists'
```

or

```
root_folder = r'C:\Users\Robert\Videos\YouTube\Playlists'
```

And then do something like:

```
my_path = os.path.join(root_folder, p[0])
if not os.path.exists(my_path):
    # ...
```

**Note:** From the official [`os.path.join()` doc](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not `c:\foo`.

Judging by the useful [*Spencer Rathbun*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717411/python-create-directory-and-move-specific-file/9717595#comment12359678_9717595) example, on windows you should get:

```
>>> os.path.join('C', 'users')
'C\\users'
>>> os.path.join('C:','users')
'C:users'
```

Which means that you must use either one of the following:

```js
>>> os.path.join('C:/', 'users')
'C:\\users'
>>> os.path.join(r'C:\', 'users')
'C:\\users'
```

Comment: python has no problem with forward slashes in windows paths, it converts them automatically when you use an os-based command (e.g. shutil.move).

Comment: @aquavitae: Good to know, I wasn't sure of that. Is it one way more used/perfered than the other?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I tend to use forward slashes to keep compatibility (as far as possible considering drive letters) with linux.  When I do use backslashes, I generally use a raw string to avoid escaping them.

Comment: @aquavitae: I tried googling a bit to find more info. I've never seen them with forward slashes, to me with backslashes is more readable and then you can let python do the work for you, but it seems to be just a matter of taste. I'll update my answer, thanks.

Comment: Good to know that os.path.join should be preferred over string formatting. Thanks!

Comment: `os.path.join` has a minor caveat on windows. If you include the drive letter in the path, you must use `drive:[/\]` syntax. That is, a drive letter, then colon, then slash. Otherwise, python will assume it is a relative path name. For example: `os.path.join('C', 'users') = r'C\users'` and `os.path.join('C:','users') = r'C:users'`

Comment: @SpencerRathbun: Good comment! I tried to include your comment in the answer to give it more visibility, if I said something wrong, please feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 2):

$ sign is not a valid character for string formatting, use % instead:

```
root_folder = 'C:/Users/Robert/Videos/YouTube/Playlists/$s'
print root_folder % 'testfolder'
```

Gives me: 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

```
root_folder = 'C:/Users/Robert/Videos/YouTube/Playlists/%s'
print root_folder % 'testfolder'
```

Gives me: 'C:/Users/Robert/Videos/YouTube/Playlists/testfolder'